# Besides annotations, how do I distinguish JAX-WS from JAX-RPC?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

Two questions

Two questions on JAX-WS and JAX-RPC

1. Besides annotations, how do I distinguish JAX-WS from JAX-RPC?
2. What simple POCs can I do to appreciate JAX-WS is better to use than JAX-RPC? (besides the reason that JAX-RPC is the older version). I have read all about JAX-WS and it's advantages but I find it card to figure out thinking of concrete examples or simple proof of concept that would prove that its better use it than JAX-RPC.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question is covered by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912032/how-to-determine-if-a-java-web-service-is-jax-ws-or-jax-rpc/26941568#26941568).  To summarize, there are descriptor files present for JAX-RPC, since it uses XML mapping documents to describe reflection-based rules for marshal/unmarshal.

As for your second question, I suggest writing the same HelloService web service (provider) using both frameworks.  I think you'll find JAX-WS much easier, if for no other reason than finding tutorial documentation.  Use two web modules and follow tutorials to create the same functionality.

Take a look at the artifacts for both. Also experiment with adding complex Java types as input or output. Notice that JAX-RPC cannot automatically convert many WSDL/schema constructs to a Java equivalent - a great side by side comparison article (and series) [is here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc2/index.html).

A personal anecdote - due to the JAXB underpinnings, the JAX-WS service will be much more forgiving if the request message has small deviations from the WSDL such as unexpected input elements, etc. Why is this important? Versioning & maintenance. With JAX-RPC, it was much more difficult to update the service provider with new fields without breaking JAX-RPC client applications, and vice versa.

**Spec Time**

I've seen it mentioned that JAX-RPC is deprecated as of JavaEE 6.  I don't see that wording specifically (it is listed for server implementors as "proposed optional"; [the PDF spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/javaee-6.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says the following:

> **EE.12.2.3**
>
> JAX-WS JAX-WS, along with JAXB and the Metadata for Web
>   Services specification, provides simpler and more complete support for
>   web services than is available using the JAX-RPC technology.
>   **Applications that provide web services using JAX-RPC should consider
>   migrating to the JAX-WS API**.

(emphasis mine).

The [JavaEE 7 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-eval-spec/index.html) lists JAX-RPC not only as optional (for server implementors); it also includes it in the list of "pruned Java technologies" - candidates for outright removal in subsequent JavaEE spec versions.

All this to say: you don't earn your way out of the JavaEE specification if you're the better spec.